# Angular 4 if centralize session expire handling

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am using angular 4.x

In development environment, if someone restarts the server or if user logs out from another tab and then the user keeps trying to perform some action from another tab, he/she keeps seeing the error on page.

I want centralize solution using Angular's HTTP service so that if a user is trying to perform any operation and an error due to session expiration occurs, we want to refresh the page.

Comment: is your angular version above 4.3.1? they introduced http interceptors in that version. This way you could hook in the http process and catch all responses. If the server sends an error that the session is expired, you could react to that globally

Comment: yes i am using 4.3.4

Comment: can you share example pls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's an example of an HttpInterceptor class that I got from [here](https://juristr.com/blog/2017/08/intercept-http-requests-in-angular/) (full plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/SCKXenesBaaYnYJYhWyY?p=info)).

```
@Injectable()
export class MyHttpLogInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('processing request', request);

    const customReq = request.clone({
      headers: request.headers.set('app-language', 'it')
    });

    return next
      .handle(customReq)
      .do((ev: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (ev instanceof HttpResponse) {
          console.log('processing response', ev);
        }
      })
      .catch(response => {
        if (response instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          console.log('Processing http error', response);
        }

        return Observable.throw(response);
      });
  }
}
```

The `catch` block is probably what you're interested in. You could inspect the error and check if it came from a session expire, then react to it properly.

You need to provide this Interceptor in your app.module.

```
providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MyHttpLogInterceptor, multi: true }  
  ]
```

Comment: Just a note here, I'm pretty sure that with this apporach you *have* to use the new  `HttpClientModule` and `HttpClient`, because the old Http service is not intercepted

Comment: i changed my Http service to Httpclient and interceptor worked, but i am getting 403 error. i have csrf security turn on @ server and Http service automatically takes care of including xsrf-token into the session.

Comment: using httpclient i can still see xsrf-token is being passes in request but still server returns 403 forbidden error not sure why. i think i am going to open another question for that.